# Failed to create docker image using docker slave plugin for jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to create a jenkins job that will build a github project inside a docker container that shall be generated from the Dockerfile contained in the github project itself. To do so, I am using docker slaves plugin but I am running into an issue when I run the jenkins job.

Error during container provisioning
[image]

The configuration I am using for the jenkins job is the following:

jenkins job config
[image]

So the job right now should only clone the repo and build the image. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like the image name is misconfigured in some way. It shouldn't end in a slash.

Comment: As @jordanm mentioned you are putting a extra `/` at the end of `jenkins/agent/`, it should be `jenkins/agent`

Comment: I removed the / from the jenkins global config, but the error is still showing up. What I don't understand is in which step is the image being built, because it is set so the image gets built from the Dockerfile. But the clone doesn't seem to be getting cloned.

Comment: are you able to spawn up slaves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to set the remoting image to jenkinsci/slave in the global configuration of jenkins

[Jenkins global config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNjkU.png)